# i am getting stack : Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, api

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form  name = "test_form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" >
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
<script>

var url = "http://x.x.x.x:3001/createData"
var data ={
    "productID": document.test_form.firstname,
    "title": document.test_form.lastname,


};
var success_func = function(data){
    //do what you want with the returned data
 console.log("your data is succesfull posted")
};
$.post(url, data, success_func);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am not ittrating through anything also just calling the rest api and posting the data but i am  getting stack  maximum size exceded error plese help me

Comment: remove the submit button and create a new button or element outside the form ... add an event on that and go ahead with your task.

Comment: convert this `<input type="submit" value="Submit" >` to this `<input type="button" value="Submit" >`

Comment: well ... you never call `fck` ... so why would it execute? How did you think the browser would know to run fck

Comment: dont hard cdoe ip addresses unless  you wanna expose your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code and check if it works

```js
function goodCall(){
  var url = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData"
  var data ={
    "productID": document.test_form.firstname.value,
    "title": document.test_form.lastname.value,
  }
  $.post( url, function( data ) {
    sucess_func();
  });
};

function success_func(data) {
  console.log('data posted')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form  name = "test_form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="goodCall()" value="Submit" >
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
```

Comment: it works but i am getting  following error 
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData 500 (Internal Server Error)
but it is working fine in  when api is tested in post man

Comment: http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData                                
 {"productID":"1014",
"title":"Movie1"

}
if you want just test with post man  plese help me

Comment: We cannot test from here, means there may cause CORS issue. You need to test it in your environment.

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the website's server, but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is. So you better check with the BE code itself. Either you might be missing something from your side or from backend.

Answer (score 0):

try this i thik its work now

```js
function fck(){
debugger;
var url = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData"
var data ={
    productID: $("#txt1").val(),
    title: $("#txt2").val(),


};
var success_func = function(data){
    //do what you want with the returned data
 alert("your data is succesfull posted")
};
$.post(url, data, success_func);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form  name = "test_form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" id="txt1">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" id="txt2">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="fck()">
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
```